# assign an existing id value to same record and new id to new record

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, etl

I'm trying to see if I can assign an id to a name every time that same record comes in. For instance, if I assign an ID E001 to John Doe, I want to be able to assign that same value to John every time I see a record of John. And if a new person comes into the picture, I want to pick the next ID from a list I created (table ID) and assign it to that person and so on. I'm open to suggestions or ideas or better ways on how to go about doing it either SQL (preferably) or some ETL approach. Thanks

Month 1 file (or another table in oracle)

```
Name       Addr      Location
------------------------------
John Doe  123 Main   NA
John Doe  123 Main   NA
Bob Lava  456 Tel    US
```

ORACLE_TABLE in month 1

```
ID    Name       Addr       Location
-------------------------------------
E001   John Doe  123 Main   NA
E001   John Doe  123 Main   NA
E002   Bob Lava  456 Tel    US
```

Month 2 files (or oracle table)

```
Name       Addr       Location
-------------------------------
Denny Fry 456 str    AB
John Doe  123 Main   NA
John Doe  123 Main   NA
Bob Lava  456 Tel    US
```

ORACLE TABLE in month 2 (simply append month 2 files to existing data but using previously assigned ID for existing records and a new id for a new record)

```
ID    Name       Add       Location
------------------------------------
E001   John Doe  123 Main   NA
E001   John Doe  123 Main   NA
E002   Bob Lava  456 Tel    US
E003   Denny Fry 456 str    AB
E001   John Doe  123 Main   NA
E001   John Doe  123 Main   NA
E002   Bob Lava  456 Tel    US
```

ID table list (used to assign IDs to records)

```
E001
E002
E003
E004
B001
```

Comment: You need to store a look up table with the mapping between ids and your data.  Otherwise, the ids are likely to change from one month to the next.  If you have an "original" date of some sort that doesn't change, then that would allow you to do this dynamically.

Comment: You mean original date on the ID table list? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a SQL solution in which first do `union all` and then you can use `dense_rank()` as following

```
select
  Name,
  Addr,
  Location,
  'E00' || dense_rank() over (order by Name) as EmpId
from
(
  select
    Name,
    Addr,
    Location
  from monthOne

  union all

  select
    Name,
    Addr,
    Location
  from monthTwo
) val
order by
 EmpId
```

output:

```
*-----------------------------------*
| NAME       ADDR   LOCATION  EMPID |
*-----------------------------------*
|Bob Lava   456 Tel    US     E001  |
|Bob Lava   456 Tel    US     E001  |
|Denny Fry  456 str    AB     E002  |
|John Doe   123 Main   NA     E003  |
|John Doe   123 Main   NA     E003  |
|John Doe   123 Main   NA     E003  |
|John Doe   123 Main   NA     E003  |
*-----------------------------------*
```